# Access Denied while sending simple Ajax call

Tags: html, ajax, https, internet-explorer-11

I am currently stuck with IE11 which is clients choice. I need to call local services on localhost to activate a scanner from https page. Its working fine on edge and all other browsers but on IE11 , i am facing Access Denied . I even tried with XMLhttp request but same result. There maybe some network restriction or SSL certificate error but unable to find error. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Please populate your question with code example, url your're requesting and the console output

Comment: My issue is that its working on some machines in IE11 and in some machines its not. So i think issue is some IE security setting as i am calling https to service on local host. If i try this form http call to local host , everything works fine but when i send call from https to localhost it send Access denied . all are working well on all other browsers but not on IE11.

Comment: You can try to check if the site is running in compatibility view and add this tag in the head: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" >`. You can also try to add the site to the "Trusted sites" security zone. Besides, please check the setting **Access data sources across domains** in security settings and try to enable the setting.